# Node.js command throwing errors in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, wordpress, xampp, divi

I am attempting to add an additional functionality to the Divi WordPress theme.  To do this, I am trying to build an extension to the theme and then a custom module within the extension.  Elegant Themes, the developer of Divi, provides a tutorial for [creating an extension](https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/developers/create-divi-extension/) and also for [creating a module](https://www.elegantthemes.com/documentation/developers/divi-module/how-to-create-a-divi-builder-module/) within the extension.

My development PC is running XAMPP over Ubuntu 20.04.  I followed the tutorials and installed WordPress + Divi.  I then installed Node.js by running `sudo apt install node` and then installed npm by running `sudo apt install npm`. Next, I ran `sudo npm install -g yarn` to install Yarn.

The next step called for me to navigate to the plugins folder (`/opt/lampp/htdocs/development/wp-content/plugins`) of my WordPress site and run `npx create-divi-extension development-1`.

When I attempted to run this command, I received the following response:

```
dev@dev:/opt/lampp/htdocs/development/wp-content/plugins$ npx create-divi-extension development-1
npx: installed 174 in 11.696s

Creating a new Divi extension in /opt/lampp/htdocs/development/wp-content/plugins/development-1.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and divi-scripts...

yarn add v1.22.11
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
warning divi-scripts > babel-eslint@8.2.2: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
warning divi-scripts > eslint-loader@1.9.0: This loader has been deprecated. Please use eslint-webpack-plugin
warning divi-scripts > extract-text-webpack-plugin@3.0.2: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
warning divi-scripts > html-webpack-plugin@2.30.1: out of support
warning divi-scripts > fsevents@1.1.3: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning divi-scripts > @babel/runtime > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
warning divi-scripts > autoprefixer > browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning divi-scripts > divi-dev-utils > browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning divi-scripts > css-loader > cssnano > autoprefixer > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning divi-scripts > node-sass > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning divi-scripts > node-sass > node-gyp > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp@0.6.39: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will recieve updates in the future
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > request@2.81.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning divi-scripts > grunt-contrib-compress > iltorb@2.4.5: The zlib module provides APIs for brotli compression/decompression starting with Node.js v10.16.0, please use it over iltorb
warning divi-scripts > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin > uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0
warning divi-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning divi-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
warning divi-scripts > css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning divi-scripts > node-sass > request > har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > request > har-validator@4.2.1: this library is no longer supported
warning divi-scripts > node-sass > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > request > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning divi-scripts > webpack-dev-server > sockjs > uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
warning divi-scripts > node-sass > node-gyp > tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > tar-pack > tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > request > hawk@3.1.3: This module moved to @hapi/hawk. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
warning divi-scripts > webpack > watchpack > watchpack-chokidar2 > chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
warning divi-scripts > css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > caniuse-api > browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
warning divi-scripts > eslint > file-entry-cache > flat-cache > circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > hawk > sntp@1.0.9: This module moved to @hapi/sntp. Please make sure to switch over as this distribution is no longer supported and may contain bugs and critical security issues.
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > hawk > cryptiles@2.0.5: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > hawk > boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > hawk > cryptiles > boom@2.10.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > hawk > hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > hawk > sntp > hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning divi-scripts > fsevents > node-pre-gyp > hawk > boom > hoek@2.16.3: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
warning divi-scripts > jest > @jest/core > jest-haste-map > sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
warning divi-scripts > svgr > h2x-core > h2x-parse > jsdom > request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning divi-scripts > webpack > node-libs-browser > url > querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
warning divi-scripts > babel-jest > babel-plugin-istanbul > istanbul-lib-instrument > babel-template > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
warning divi-scripts > css-loader > cssnano > postcss-merge-rules > postcss-selector-parser > flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
warning divi-scripts > svgr > h2x-core > h2x-parse > jsdom > request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
warning divi-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > braces > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
warning divi-scripts > webpack-dev-server > chokidar > braces > snapdragon > source-map-resolve > urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
error grunt-po2mo@0.1.5: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "12.x || 14.x". Got "10.19.0"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom divi-scripts --cwd /opt/lampp/htdocs/development/wp-content/plugins/development-1 has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting development-1/ from /opt/lampp/htdocs/development/wp-content/plugins
Done.
```

When I run `node -v` I receive `v.10.19.0` as a response and when I run `npm -v` I get `6.14.4`.

At this point, this issue is somewhat beyond my expertise and quite confusing to me.  All that I can come to understand is that `divi-scripts` and `fsevents` are outdated.  I'm not sure what those are, what would cause that, or how to fix it.

If someone could provide me with some insight on this issue and some direction in resolving it, it would be much appreciated.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to update your node.js to version 12.x or 14.x

Comment: @VasylMoskalov I figured it out.  I had to update Node to 14. by using `sudo n stable` and then run `npm install divi-scripts` in my home folder.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a result of not using the correct version of Node and not having the `divi-scripts` package installed.  The fix was simple really.

Step 1:  In my home directory, I ran `sudo n stable` and this updated Node to the latest LTS version.

Step 2:  While still in my home directory, I ran `npm install divi-scripts`.  There were still some errors about deprecated dependencies ([see here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/divi-scripts)) but it worked.

Step 3:  Navigated to my project folder and ran `npx create-divi-extension development-1` and it ran successfully, but still with errors about deprecated dependencies for `divi-scripts`.